# Flatten rows in R data frame by column match

Tags: r, dictionary, concatenation, flatten

I have a dataset that looks something like this.

```
  year recipient amount  id
1 1973    AG      17      7
2 1973    AG      18      7
3 1974    BE      20      9
4 1974    BE      22      9
5 1975    AG      20      7
6 1975    AG      25      7
```

I'm trying to flatten the rows so that there is only a single row for each recipient per year. I'd like to transform the amount variable to be equal to the sum of all amounts over that year. My ideal result looks like this:

```
  year recipient amount id
1 1973    AG      35     7
2 1974    BE      42     7
3 1975    AG      45     7
```

I tried writing a loop to accomplish this, but I think that there has to be an easier way that I'm just not familiar with. Maybe a map or flatten function somewhere in a package?

Comment: `aggregate(amount ~ ., data, sum)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(year, recipient, id) %>% summarise(amount=sum(amount))
Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
Groups: year, recipient

  year recipient id amount
1 1973        AG  7     35
2 1974        BE  9     42
3 1975        AG  7     45
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.

Comment: I'm not familiar with dplyr, so forgive me if this is a stupid question. How would I keep other variables in the resulting dataset that will stay the same, like the id variable I just added to the question?

Comment: You just include the variable as a further grouping variable. I edited the answer

Comment: Could I use this to flatted rows with string values, where the desired summarisation is simply taking the non-null value (I know there's always only 1 across all related rows)? How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is probably more power than you need for this simple example, but for this sort of thing, I love the sqldf library which allows you to manipulate data frames like they are database tables using SQL.  In your case

```
library(sqldf)
newdf <- sqldf("SELECT year,recipient,id,sum(amount) as amount from olddf group by year,recipient,id")
```

by default it uses SQLite as a backend, so it can work with fairly complex SQL statements.  I usually find R's data manipulation language to be a little confusing, and ALWAYS have to look up what I'm trying to do, so using SQL instead can be very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, list(amount=sum(amount), id= id[1L]) ,.(year, recipient)]
#   year recipient amount id
#1: 1973        AG     35  7
#2: 1974        BE     42  9
#3: 1975        AG     45  7
```

Or if "id" should be also a grouping variable

```
setDT(df1)[, list(amount=sum(amount)), .(year, recipient, id)]
```